# Changing value of a data attribute in client side mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a grid displaying search results in Asp.Net MVC4. Please see it below.

```
div id="searchResultsArea" style="display:inline">
                <%: Html.Grid(Model.SearchResults.PagedList)
                    .Columns(columnBuilder =>
                    {
                        ...
                        columnBuilder.For(o => o.SpecialName)
                            .Attributes(style => "text-align:center")
                            .SortColumnName("SpecialName")
                            .Named("SpecialName");
                    })
                    .Attributes(id => "searchResults", @class => "selectable")
                    .Sort(ViewData["sort"] as GridSortOptions)
                    .Empty("No Results Found.")
```

Here, SpecialName is a boolean field, so it is coming as true or false. I would like to change "false" into empty string. So, the grid should show an empty string under SpecialName column if the value is false, but it should show "true" if the value is true. Is there any way to do it in the client side?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide samples of your model and controller classes?

Comment: Yes, you can do it client side, using plain javascript or jquery....can you post the generated html code for one row?

Answer (score 0):

try this way.

```
  $(".ClassName").attr("data-SpecialName").val("YOUR NEW VALUE")
```